# Root vs bootstrap component

Tags: angular

I have the following query. `Is always the root component in Angular Component tree the bootstrap one`? Is there any possibility of another component, apart from the one which bootstraps, to be the root component?

So far, my understanding is there is **one Component tree** (no matter how many modules are there) and the **bootstrap component** inside the **bootstrap module** is the root of the above tree. *Am I correct or not?*

```
constructor(private app: ApplicationRef) {
    let element = this.app.components[0];
    console.log(element);
}
```

*Does the above code log the root component?* I thought `this.app.components`
would include all the components of the component tree but it does not. *Is there any way to get all of them programmatically?*

Comment: It's modules that are bootstrapped, not components, no? I tried to bootstrap my Nav module, for fun, but of course it has no references to the core angular modules, so fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can exist multiple bootstrapped component tree. That's the reason  the bootstrap parameter can take an array of classes instead of single class.

From Angular's official doc (https://angular.io/guide/bootstrapping#the-bootstrap-array)

> Each bootstrapped component is the base of its own tree of components. Inserting a bootstrapped component usually triggers a cascade of component creations that fill out that tree

I have added a small plunkr to demonstrate multiple bootstrapped components.
https://plnkr.co/edit/ChAl9N9O5cOcojNlKl0D?p=preview

**app.ts**

```
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Child Number {{count}}</h2>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class Child {

  static counter: number = 1;

  count: number;

  constructor() {
    this.count = Child.counter++;
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app-1',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Component Tree 1</h2>
      <child></child>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App1 {
  constructor() {
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app-2',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Component Tree 2</h2>
      <child></child>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App2 {
  constructor() {
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ Child, App1, App2 ],
  bootstrap: [ App1, App2 ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <base href="." />
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
      window.AngularVersionForThisPlunker = 'latest'
    </script>
    <title>angular playground</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/core-js@2.4.1/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/reflect-metadata@0.1.3/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/systemjs@0.19.31/dist/system.js"></script>
    <script src="config.js"></script>
    <script>
    System.import('app')
      .catch(console.error.bind(console));
  </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <my-app-1>
    loading...
    </my-app-1>
    <my-app-2>
    loading...
    </my-app-2>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, components can be detached of eachother and does not have to compose a hierarchy tree.

Comment: However, in case there is a hierarchy tree, is my assumption true?

Comment: You can have many trees as root component is the same component as every else. It just starts the tree hierarchy. Its only a metter of design

Comment: Do you know any good source as to read some more stuff about that? I did not find anything good by myself.

Comment: Not rly no. Did you check angular 4 documentation?

Comment: Can you provide a link or at least an app example where you have multiple app hierarchy trees? I'm not talking about multiple-apps-per-page scenario, I'm aware of those. I'm asking if you know of any single app, multiple trees examples or could provide one.